# What does Mecanim's "loop pose" parameter do?

Tags: unity, skeletal-animation, mecanim

What exactly does the *loop pose* parameter do?

What's the difference between enabling or disabling it on animation clips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop Pose: Enable to make the motion loop seamlessly.

It keeps looping the pose. Meaning, that you have same pose at begin frame and end frame.

Comment: so it should be checked only for animations that actually loop, right?

Comment: Yes. Animations that loop back to start frame. So, think animation for breathing. It loops lungs full of air, then releases it and gets back to original pose.

Comment: A common use for this check box is in things like movement animations (run cycles, for example) from motion-capture.  Unless your mo-cap actor is incredibly consistent in his or her movements, generally the end of a run cycle will not be *exactly* the same pose as the start of that cycle, so looping it would contain a noticeable pop once per cycle.  Checking that box blends the end pose to the start pose, so the run cycle looks seamless.